# Run Update Query with Warnings off doesn't run the query

Tags: ms-access, events, macros, warnings

I have a field in a Form, and an After Update Event on that field.

In the Macros, I turn off the warnings with `WarningsOn = No` action
and then run my update query with an `OpenQuery` action.

The query is supposed to update 4 fields, but doesn't. Now when I remove the `WarningsOn = No` action, the query runs after updating the field. But I am prompted with 2 message boxes asking me if I am sure that I want to update the relevant fields.

I did that kind of thing before and it was working, but now somehow it is not. Any idea why ?

Comment: Why 2 message boxes? Second one about errors? Probably you need to fix errors first.

Comment: You can turn off the action query warnings permanently in the Access settings. But these warnings are irrelevant to whether the queries run or not, something else is going on.